# Lift's JavaScript abstraction layer

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

I am trying to run the following example from "Exploring Lift" book (with small changes, i.e. I preferred CSS-binding over XML-binding):

```
object Hello {
  import js.{JxMap, Jx, JsCmds, JE}
  import JE._
  import net.liftweb.http.SHtml._
  import net.liftweb.util.BindHelpers._
  import JsCmds._

  val names = "marius" :: "tyler" :: "derek" :: "dave" :: "jorge" :: "viktor" :: Nil
  def ajaxian =
    "#text" #> ajaxText("Type something", {value => {
      val matches = names.filter(e => e.indexOf(value) > -1)
      SetHtml("items_list", NodeSeq.Empty) &
      JsCrVar("items", JsArray(matches.map(Str(_)):_*)) &
      JsCrVar("func", Jx(<ul>{
        JxMap(JsVar("it"), Jx(<li>{JsVar("it")}</li>))
      }</ul>).toJs) &
      (ElemById("items_list") ~> JsFunc("appendChild", Call("func", JsVar("items"))))
    }})
}
```

But I keep getting a list of "JsExp(it)" items when rendered to an HTML page instead of names in the same-named list. There should be something wrong with line

```
JxMap(JsVar("it"), Jx(<li>{JsVar("it")}</li>))
```

Lift lacks of documentation on JavaScript abstraction layer and reading corresponding chapters in books and browsing the Lift's sources do not lead me to an understanding of what's going on. The only thing I could figure up to now is that `Jx` creates `AnonFunc` with `it` parameter but I can not convince myself into correct usage of `JsVar("it")` in the example provided by Derek in his book.